# Snaps on elementary

Tags: applications, camera

I have an issue with a snap elementary. I just installed the polarr photo editor and I think it's using an incorrect resolution. How can I correct this?

Comment: You're referring to the following snap? https://snapcraft.io/polarr
Could you include some info on your system, like what's your dpi (You could use the Dippi app to check this)? Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce the issue. I have a 4K 282 DPI screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit embarrassing, sorry, but I've just reopened the app to take a screenshot and it seems the problem has gone away, everything looks okay now. Thanks for your time!

Comment: None of us want to see issues when installing new apps but an issue such as this is cool...one that solves itself, LOL! No need for the embarrassment and glad all is well!!!